# VFX Graph - Flipbook not looping

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system, visual-effects

**SITUATION**

I am using Unity's **Visual Effect Graph** to make a smoke effect. I am using the **HDRP**.

**PROBLEM**

My flipbook is not looping, for some reason. When the flipbook's end is reached, the smoke trail simply disappears.

**SETTINGS**

The "UV Mode" is currently set to "Flipbook Motion Blend" but the other settings don't work either.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!

I just needed to change the image settings from "Wrap mode: clamp" to "Repeat"

[image]